# Why does Frame.ofRecords garbles its results when fed a sequence generated by a parallel calculation?

Tags: parallel-processing, f#, deedle

I am running some code that calculates a sequence of records and calls `Frame.ofRecords` with that sequence as its argument. The records are calculated using `PSeq.map` from the library `FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq`.

If I convert the sequence into a list then the output is OK. Here is the code and the output:

```
let summaryReport path (writeOpenPolicy: WriteOpenPolicy) (outputs: Output seq) =
    let foo (output: Output) =
        let temp =
            { Name          = output.Name
              Strategy      = string output.Strategy
              SharpeRatio   = (fst output.PandLStats).SharpeRatio
              CalmarRatio   = (fst output.PandLStats).CalmarRatio }
        printfn "************************************* %A" temp
        temp
    outputs
    |> Seq.map foo
    |> List.ofSeq // this is the line that makes a difference
    |> Frame.ofRecords
    |> frameToCsv path writeOpenPolicy ["Name"] "Summary_Statistics"


Name    Name        Strategy    SharpeRatio CalmarRatio
0   Singleton_AAPL  MyStrategy  0.317372564 0.103940018
1   Singleton_MSFT  MyStrategy  0.372516931 0.130150478
2   Singleton_IBM   MyStrategy              Infinity
```

The `printfn` command let me verify by inspection that in each case the variable `temp` was calculated correctly.
The last code line is just a wrapper around `FrameExtensions.SaveCsv`.

If I remove the `|> List.ofSeq` line then what comes out is garbled:

```
Name    Name        Strategy    SharpeRatio CalmarRatio
0   Singleton_IBM   MyStrategy  0.317372564 0.130150478
1   Singleton_MSFT  MyStrategy              0.103940018
2   Singleton_AAPL  MyStrategy  0.372516931 Infinity
```

Notice that the empty (corresponding to `NaN`) and `Infinity` items are now in different lines and other things are also mixed up.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Frame.ofRecords` function iterates over the sequence multiple times, so if your sequence returns different data when called repeatedly, you will get inconsistent data into the frame.

Here is a minimal example:

```
let mutable n = 0.
let nums = seq { for i in 0 .. 10 do n <- n + 1.; yield n, n }

Frame.ofRecords nums
```

This returns:

```
      Item1 Item2 
0  -> 1     12    
1  -> 2     13    
2  -> 3     14    
3  -> 4     15    
4  -> 5     16    
5  -> 6     17    
6  -> 7     18    
7  -> 8     19    
8  -> 9     20    
9  -> 10    21    
10 -> 11    22
```

As you can see, the first item is obtained during the first iteration of the sequence, while the second items is obtained during the second iteration.

This should probably be better documented, but it makes the performance better in typical scenarios - if you can send a PR to the docs, that would be useful.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me a hint on how to send a PR to the docs?

Comment: @Soldalma - The docs are in the https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle repository. If you have done PRs for other Github projects, that should be all you need to get you started.

Comment: @rmunn - I looked into it and I am not comfortable doing a PR. Afraid I could damage something. In any case, all I can think of doing is to convert the sequence to a list before `Frame.ofRecords` processes it. Any other alternative would be quite complicated and probably also very slow.

Comment: @Soldalma - It is not possible to damage anything :) if your PR breaks something, we will not merge/accept it (and instead point you in the right direction on how to make it better!)

Comment: @Tomas - I tried and soon got lost. I have never done a PR before and I don't know what I am supposed to do. Sorry. I am an economist, not a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel Sequences are run in arbitrary order, because they get split across many processors therefore the result-set will be in random order. You can always sort them afterwards, or not run your data in parallel.

Comment: I do not think the problem is that the sequence got out of order. As I observed the problem was not that the lines got out of order. That would not be a problem. The problem is that the figures got scrambled vertically. For example, in the first row of the first table one sees the numbers 0.317372564 and 0.130150478. This combination of numbers does not appear in any one of the three rows in the second table. If all that was happening was that the items were unsorted this combination of numbers would have to appear is one of the three rows of the second table.